# How should I fix run time error 424 object required in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I wrote a VBA in Excel to find a specific word in Microsoft Word and get parts of the table right below that keyword back to Excel however it gives a Runtime error 424 "object required", your help would be much appreciated. Thank you !

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim objWord As Object
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim strValue As String
        Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
        Dim wdFileName As Variant
        Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

        objWord.Visible = True
        Set wdDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\Testt.docx")
        objWord.Activate


        With objWord.Selection.Find
        .Forward = True
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute FindText:="Test"
        End With
        If objWord.Selection.Find.Execute = True Then
        MsgBox ("Found")
        Else
        MsgBox ("Not found")
         End If



    TableNo = objWord.Selection.Tables.Count
    Dim a As Object
       Set a = objWord.Selection.Range.Next(Unit:=TableNo, Count:=1)




    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    x = 1: y = 1
    With a
    For rowNb = 1 To 1
    For colNb = 2 To 2
    Cells(x, y) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(rowNb, colNb).Range.Text)
    y = y + 1
    Next colNb
    y = 1
    x = x + 1
    Next rowNb
    End With
    x = x + 2








    End Sub
```

Object required Runtime error 424 on this line:

```
Cells(x, y) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(rowNb, colNb).Range.Text)
```

Comment: You really should `Dim a`.

Comment: Thank you, I thought of that using Option Explicit, but As what should a be Dim? Dim a As ...? I'm assigning the 1st table found after the keyword in that a

Comment: `Range.Next` returns `Range` (which is a Word Range) so if you're late-binding it should be `As Object`.

Comment: But there's no `.Cell` - there's [`Cells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.cells). And I don't think you index them like that, but could be wrong.

Comment: Cheers ! I declared Dim a As Object , now I'm getting a different error. Runtime error 91 "Object variable or With block not set" on this line     a = objWord.Selection.Range.Next(Unit:=TableNo, Count:=1).Select

Comment: I'm not an expert in word, but try `Set a = objWord.Selection.Range.Next(Unit:=TableNo, Count:=1)`.

Comment: Regarding the .Cell commentary. I tried that without grabbing the 1st table after the keyword such as inputting the table by number and it worked with .Cell

Comment: Added "Set a = objWord.Selection.Range.Next(Unit:=TableNo, Count:=1)" yields runtime error 462 remote server machine not found

Comment: Ah my bad completely, see I'm no expert in Word, it's [`Table.Cell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table.cell). So `a` might not be a `Range` after all. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: Right, I tried assigning a as the 1st table that was found right after the keyword and then copy specific cells from the Word table back to Excel, no problem

Comment: Hi I added the Word 16.0 from Tools References and I considered the Explicit Option but still has errors

Comment: This line 'If objWord.Selection.Find.Text > 0 Then' tests if the string 'Test' is >0.  !!!!

Comment: use = True then?

Comment: Now you need to deal with the erros one by one.  If you get stuck put the cursor on a keyword and press F1.  This will bring up the Microsoft help page for that keyword.  This works for the Office object models as well as VBA keywords.

Comment: I tried but I got stuck here, I got confused

Comment: Well for a start put the cursor on the word 'find' and press f1.  Then when you understand how the Word VBA Find object works you will understand why the above line cannot be resolved by wildly guessing the answer.

Comment: Yes, I looked but I don't get what's wrong, it sort of finds my keyword, if I delete it says it didn't find. I tried this  If objWord.Selection.Find.Text = True Then and it just says it doesen't find despite the string being there. I tried my best, I'm at the beginning but I really got confused now

Comment: Well, if you have no .execute command in your code you are not searching for a word, you are just checking a  property of the text you defined as your search text.

Comment: Updated the above code, now it basically opens the Word it finds the keyword highlights it, but shows "Not found". Tried something like: With objWord.Selection.Find .Forward = True .ClearFormatting .MatchWholeWord = True .MatchCase = False .Wrap = wdFindContinue .Execute FindText:="Test" End With If objWord.Selection.Find.Execute = True Then MsgBox ("Found") Else MsgBox ("Not found") End If

Comment: Sorry, my username is Nigel, I subcopied from other user by mistake, can you edit the comment please, so it can be easier? Cheers !

Comment: I updated the code accordingly, unfortunately despite highlighting the found keyword it will show "Not found". Would you be kind to edit on the above code, please? I would be more than grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid an infinite sequence of comments try the code below as a guide to where you should be going.  There may still be issues to fix to get to the logic you were thinking of, rather than my interpretation of it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim objWord As Word.Application
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim strValue As String
        Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
        Dim wdFileName As Variant
        Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
        Dim myTableRange As Word.Range ' formerly variable 'a'

        Set objWord = New Word.Application
        Set wdDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\Testt.docx")

        objWord.Activate
        objWord.Visible = True

        ' The use of selection here is incorrect because the cursor
        '(selection point) will just be at the start of the document
        ' so we actuially need to tell word a range to use
        ' we also need to use the document and not the application
        With wdDoc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)

            With .Find
                .Forward = True
                .ClearFormatting
                .MatchWholeWord = True
                .MatchCase = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Text = "Test"
                .Execute

            End With

            If .Find.Found Then
                MsgBox "Found"
            Else
                MsgBox "Not found"
                Exit Sub
            End If

            ' duplicate just makes a copy of the current found range
            Set myTableRange = .Duplicate.Next(unit:=wdTable)
        End With

    Dim rowNb As Long
    Dim ColNb As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    x = 1
    y = 1

    With myTableRange.Tables(1)
        For rowNb = 1 To 1 '
            For ColNb = 2 To 2
                ' its not clear where you are referring to word or excel cells.
                ' you will need to change the qualifications for the cell parts as appropriate
                .Cell(x, y).Range.Text = WorksheetFunction.Clean(myTableRange.Tables(1).Cell(rowNb, ColNb).Range.Text)
                ' the line below will be executed but its value will never be used
                y = y + 1
            Next ColNb
            ' these two lines will be executed but thier values will never be used
            y = 1
            x = x + 1
        Next rowNb
    End With
    ' the line below will be executed but its value will never be used
    x = x + 2

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ! How can I make the search range for the specific keyword start say from the 5th page of the Word Document, until the End of it. Thinking of replacing the following With wdDoc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)

Comment: with something like this: Set DocRange = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0) Set DocRange = DocRange.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=5) Set DocRange = DocRange.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page") DocRange.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End